# What CHMOD does the Configuration.php from Joomla need?

Tags: php, joomla, chmod, rights

I just looked into the Joomla File-permissions in the Backend and saw that the `Configuration.php` can't be written because it uses a 444 is this the correct CHMOD or do I need something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration.php need readonly "0444", same for:

```
index.php  
/administrator/index.php  
/templates/your_template/index.php  
All „.htaccess“-Files  
All Files with „.css“
```

Directory should have „0755“
and File generaly „0644“

Comment: should I change the files you listed to 0444? Because they have 0644 at the moment (except configuration.php)

Comment: Do it for security reason.   But don't forget that you can become trouble with readonly if you want edit this file via a FTP-Client. Then you must change the permisson back.